# Distribute partitioned IgniteCache on selected nodes only along deployed Service

Tags: java, ignite

I am running an Apache Ignite cluster with various nodes which provide services. Each node is assigned a certain service group (custom node attributes) describing the service which is being provided by this node, e.g. Authorization, Payment, ...

Some of these services are utilizing the Ignite Cache but I want these service specific caches deployed on the associated service nodes only. So I am adding a node filter to my cache configuration:

```
// configuration with custom attribute is provided at node start up
IgniteConfiguration nodeConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
Map<String,String> nodeAttributes = Collections.singletonMap("role", "MyService");
nodeConfig.setUserAttributes(nodeAttributes);

CacheConfiguration cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("MyServiceCache");
cfg.setNodeFilter((node) -> node.attribute("role") == nodeConfig .getUserAttributes().get("role"));
```

The cache deployment is working as expected (at least no errors are shown). However when I add a 2nd node which provides the same service (for reasons of scaling) a log entry is shown:

`No server nodes found for cache client: MyServiceCache`

As soon as I stop the 2nd node another log message is showing up:

```
[17:26:29] Topology snapshot [ver=9, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.7GB]
[17:26:29] All server nodes for the following caches have left the cluster: 'MyServiceCache'
[17:26:29] Must have server nodes for caches to operate.
```

As far as I understand the 1st node should still be serving the service and cache. So these messages do not make much sense to me. Can someone elaborate please?

Here's a concrete example:

- Run `MyService.java` twice or more
- Stop 1st node
- Watch log output of 2nd node

*NodeConfig.java*

```
public class NodeConfig {

    public static IgniteConfiguration myServiceNode()
    {
        IgniteConfiguration nodeConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
        Map<String,String> nodeAttributes = Collections.singletonMap("role", "myService");
        nodeConfig.setUserAttributes(nodeAttributes);
        return nodeConfig;
    }

}
```

*CacheConfig.java*

```
public class CacheConfig {

    public static CacheConfiguration<Long, String> myServiceCache() {

        CacheConfiguration<Long, String> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("MyServiceCache");

        cfg.setBackups(2);

        cfg.setNodeFilter((node) -> node.attribute("role") == NodeConfig.myServiceNode().getUserAttributes().get("role"));

        return cfg;
    }

}
```

*MyService.java*

```
public class MyService implements Service {

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;
    private IgniteCache cache;

    @Override
    public void cancel(ServiceContext serviceContext) {
        System.out.println("Service " + serviceContext.name() + " cancelled.");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServiceContext serviceContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Service " + serviceContext.name() + " initialized.");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(ServiceContext serviceContext) throws Exception {

        CacheConfiguration config = CacheConfig.myServiceCache();
        cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(config).withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(Duration.ONE_MINUTE));

        System.out.println("Service " + serviceContext.name() + " executing.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(NodeConfig.myServiceNode());

        IgniteServices svcs = ignite.services(ignite.cluster().forAttribute("role", NodeConfig.myServiceNode().getUserAttributes().get("role")));

        svcs.deployNodeSingleton("MyService", new MyService());

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide small example that reproduces the issue. You use case doesn't look trivial and the description is a bit vague.

Comment: Sure, I've added a concrete example.

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with the way I am deploying the service on each new node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `==` to compare attribute values. This condition works fine:

```
cfg.setNodeFilter((node) -> Objects.equals(node.attribute("role"), NodeConfig.myServiceNode().getUserAttributes().get("role")));
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. That indeed seems to fix it. Ty!

Comment: Apparently when you deploy a service this way you cannot throw/catch exceptions properly, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545051/catch-user-exception-in-remote-service-at-caller-level Any hint?